# Scope of callee-returned object w.r.t. caller local variables?

Tags: c++, scope, return-value, c++17, local-variables

Consider the following code example:

```
SomeClass Callee() {
  // Option 1:
  return SomeClass(/* initializer here */);

  // Option 2:
  SomeClass tmp(/* initializer here */);
  // Do something to tmp here
  return tmp;
}

void Caller() {
 SomeClass a(/* initializer here */);
 SomeClass b = Callee();
 SomeClass c(/* initializer here */);
}
```

AFAIK, `b` will live longer than `c` in the above example, but not longer than `a`.

However, what happens if the return value of `Callee()` is not assigned to any variable in `Caller()`? Will the returned object behave like `b` in the example above? Or will it be destructed before `c` is created? I guess it's the latter, just want to be sure.

The code example is:

```
void Caller() {
 SomeClass a(/* initializer here */);
 Callee(); // what is the scope for the object returned by it?
 SomeClass c(/* initializer here */);
}
```

Comment: This question is unclear. It mentions 2 options for function, but never references them later. Also, I do not understand the last sentence. I suggest the question to be rephrased.

Comment: Objects don't have scopes. They have lifetimes. Names have scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will be destructed even before `c` is created, on account of being a temporary. It's lifetime is the full expression involving the function call.

[[class.temporary]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4):

> When an implementation introduces a temporary object of a class that
>   has a non-trivial constructor ([class.ctor], [class.copy]), it shall
>   ensure that a constructor is called for the temporary object.
>   Similarly, the destructor shall be called for a temporary with a
>   non-trivial destructor ([class.dtor]). **Temporary objects are
>   destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that
>   (lexically) contains the point where they were created.** This is true
>   even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception. The value
>   computations and side effects of destroying a temporary object are
>   associated only with the full-expression, not with any specific
>   subexpression.